# Can we use Google Maps api and Google Places api in same android app project?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using Google Maps and Google places api in my app and getting an error in manifests file because of meta-data tags.

```
       <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

this is for google maps api.........

```
       <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>
```

this is for google places api...........

```
       <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_places_key"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same meta tag for both APIs.

Have a look at the documentation of Maps Android API and Places API for Android:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#use-key

https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start#api-key

Both mention the same meta tag

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```

So, you just create an API key, set Android app restriction, add one meta tag in manifest and it will be valid for both APIs.